# Setup a new user after it's created

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, device-policy-manager, device-owner

From my **device owner** application, I'd like to create a new user and switch directly to it. For now, I can only create a new user, switch to it but:

- it brings me to the keyguard screen, that I need to manually unlock.
- then, tells me to setup the newly created user - with firstname, lastname, WIFI settings, and 3 Google usage statistics/reporting options.

I'd like to know if there's a way to programmatically setup the new user and switch directly to it's "session". I'd like to programmatically avoid the "unlock" page et pre-setup the newly created user  with name, WIFI settings, but also available apps and security settings.

here's what I do so far :

```
// init block (in onCreate...)
DevicePolicyManager mDPM  = (DevicePolicyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName mDeviceAdminRcvr = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminRcvr.class);    

// in my button "create a new user"
ComponentName profileOwnerComponent = new ComponentName(this, ProfileAdminRcvr.class);
Bundle adminExtras = new Bundle();

UserHandle userHandle = mDPM.createAndInitializeUser(mDeviceAdminRcvr, name, ownerName, profileOwnerComponent, adminExtras);

// TODO : place here missing instructions to provision the user...
mDPM.switchUser(mDeviceAdminRcvr, userHandle);
```

I couldn't find any documentation on the official [Google page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) about **device owner apps** or **profile apps**. 
Could anyone help me or point me to useful links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've seen, there is **no way to programmatically unlock the screen lock**. Even the [Smart lock](http://www.howtogeek.com/202881/use-smart-locks-in-android-5.0-and-never-unlock-your-phone-at-home-again/) functionnality added in Lollipop will just disable the Key Guard, which means that the "PIN" or "Pattern" will transform into a "Swipe Lock" when a trusted agent unlocks the device. Even in this case, you'll need to manually swipe the screen to unlock the device.

Concerning the second point, it's possible to avoid the "Setup Wizard" proposed the first time you unlock a newly created user. Here's how to do it :

- in your `ProfileAdminRcvr.java`, you'll need to hide the system application called `com.google.android.setupwizard`. You could do this in the `onEnabled()` method of your `DeviceAdminReceiver`'s implementation (the one you set for your profile when creating the user).
- To complete this, you can disable the "first use hint", by setting the [Settings.Secure.SKIP_FIRST_USE_HINTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#SKIP_FIRST_USE_HINTS) property.

Here's the code to do it :

```
public class ProfileOwnerRcvr extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

  private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
  private ComponentName mProfileAdminRcvr;

  @Override
  public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mDPM.setProfileName(mProfileAdminRcvr, "My new user");
    // ... setup other things by yourself...        

    mDPM.setApplicationHidden( mProfileAdminRcvr, "com.google.android.setupwizard", true);
    mDPM.setSecureSetting(mProfileAdminRcvr, Settings.Secure.SKIP_FIRST_USE_HINTS, "1");

}
```

Comment: I don't think this works on Android 6. To verify I ran `adb shell am force-stop com.google.android.setupwizard` on the "Set up new user" screen after switching users, and it just disappears and re-appears. It does seem like there's a fix with Android 7 at least, in p4u114's answer.

Comment: Actually, it does work when creating it programmatically. However, the home button seems to be disabled, something that doesn't seem to happen if I create the user normally.

Answer (score 0):

Google [updated its demo app](http://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc) to use Android-N preview version, it seems that there will be a flag called `DevicePolicyManager.SKIP_SETUP_WIZARD` to do part of what you are trying to do (i.e skipping the wizard) in N.